# How to Remove JSON Object ID in php json encode function while using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT Param

Tags: php, json

Here is my PHP Code which fetches the data from DATABASE and shows as JSON Encode.

```
<?php


// Initialize variable for database credentials
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'sfm';

//Create database connection
  $dblink = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

//Check connection was successful
  if ($dblink->connect_errno) {
     printf("Failed to connect to database");
     exit();
  }

//Fetch 3 rows from actor table
  $result = $dblink->query("SELECT quote, author FROM quote ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

//Initialize array variable
 $dbdata = array();


//Fetch into associative array
  while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $dbdata[]=$row;
  }


    echo json_encode($dbdata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

?>
```

And Here is the Output I'm getting as JSON.
[image]

I Need my JSON Output Like this..
[image]
Help me.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are expecting just one row, you can ditch the loop and just fetch the first record, then encode just this row rather than an array of 1 row...

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo json_encode($row, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Not sure where the id comes from in the result, this may be just a case of adding it to the SQL select.